# Decorator won't work: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, function, decorator

```
import numpy as np

def multi_print(n):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for z in np.arange(n):
                print(func(*args))

@multi_print(2)   
def if_num(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 'abc'
    else:
        return 'def'

if_num(3)
```

I am trying to just play around with how decorators interact with functions. When I run this block of code, I get a `'NoneType' object is not callable` error. Wasn't sure why. I would expect the above code to print "def" two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator and wrapper don't return anything.  A decorator with arguments should return a decorator, and the decorator should return the wrapped function.  The fix:

```py
import numpy as np

def multi_print(n):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for z in np.arange(n):
                print(func(*args, **kwargs)) # should pass on kwargs, too
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@multi_print(2)   
def if_num(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 'abc'
    else:
        return 'def'

if_num(3)
```

Output:

```
def
def
```